# How to Change YUI Dialog Draggable?

Tags: dialog, yui, draggable

A YAHOO.widget.Dialog object can be instantiated with a boolean specifying whether the dialog should be draggable or not.

But how can I later change the draggable setting once the dialog is instantiated and available?  I don't see any way to do that in the API.  Browsing through the object in the debugger, I see the intial configuration values, but changing those don't change the behavior once active.

Comment: Maybe the applyConfig() method can later be called.  If so, is there an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"draggable" appears to be the property/attribute you want. Try doing:

```
myPanel.setProperty("draggable", false);
```

Or alternatively,

```
myPanel.setProperty("draggable", true);
```